# Kndo TreeView LoadOnDemand not hitting the server

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

for my kendo treeview, i set load on demand to true but it is not hitting the server to load childs, because the 'children' property is set for the datasource model, even its empty.

```
homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
         transport: {
            read: {
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: obj.DataSourcesURL,
                dataType: "json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options) {
                if (!options.Id) {
                    options.Id = null;

                }
                if (options.filter) {
                    options.Search = options.filter.filters[0].name;
                }
                else {
                    options.Search = '';

                }
                return JSON.stringify(options);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "d",
            errors: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log("errors");
            },
            model: {
                hasChildren: "hasChild",
                children:'items',
                id: "Id"
            }
        }
    });
```

And treeView code is

```
$treeView.kendoTreeView({
        dataTextField: 'Description',
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        },
        dataSource: homogeneous,
        loadOnDemand: loadOnDemand,
        check: function () {
            var checkedNodes = [];
            var treeView = $treeView.data("kendoTreeView");

            getCheckedNodes(treeView.dataSource.view(), checkedNodes);
            setMessage(checkedNodes.length);
        },
        dataBound: function (e) {
            if (e !== undefined)
                resetCheckedNodes(e.sender.dataItems());
        },
        messages: {
            loading: "Laden..."
        },
        expand: function (e) {
            var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.node);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `hasChildren` like this in your schema:

```
schema: {
        data: "d",
        errors: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log("errors");
        },
        model: {
            hasChildren: function(e) {
                    return e.items && e.items.length;
                },
            children:'items',
            id: "Id"
        }
    }
```

And also from your question I am not sure do you even get any data or it is only `Children` data that is not returned.  Maybe you could also show how your data structure look like.

Comment: i get data for root level but not childs, if i remove the children property from the model, everything works fine, but then if I remove it and tried to load all data together (for example as searching result), then children is not shown

Comment: Can you take a part of your data response just to see structure or make dummy data structure how your response looks like. Because if you say children: 'items' it means that your children will be like: '[{ ParentId: 123,
Name: something,
Items: {Id: 1234,Name: childName}}]' and here 'items' represent your children.

Comment: {"__type":"EDTS.ViewModel.DataTypes.TreeStructureViewModel","ParentId":null,"hasChild":true,"items":null,"expanded":false,"Id":260,"Description":"Description 1"}, note that items exists in the return object but with null value as its not loaded,